# Ubuntu VM Not Connecting To Internet

Tags: networking, server, internet, 19.04

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu on a Virtual Machine. Everything worked perfecttly including internet, until I hardcoded an IP address. Now, I am unable to connect. I verified in my router config that my DHCP range is .38 - .243 and also that .38 was not assigned to a diff device. Then I went to etc/network/interfaces and input the below, but if I run ifconfig in the terminal it's no longer showing ens33?

What must I do to hardcode an IP on this Ubuntu VM? It's Ubuntu 19.04
[image: Ubuntu]

**EDIT**
If I run `ifconfig -a` i see the missing network adapter...but still no wifi. What's my issue?

[image: two]

**Edit 2**
It appears that for some reason it has been disabled...see screenshot. I tried these two commands to re-enable but still down.

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

sudo service networking start

[image: 3]

**Edit 3**
I set the interfaces file back to default, rebooted and **BAM** internet is working again.

I clicked the computers in the top right corner, selected wired connected, wired settings, and put this as the settings (which is my valid gateway, IP and DNS)

[image: wired setttings]

Comment: Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and remove all of the ens33 stuff that you added, and uncomment lines 2 and 3, which should be the only two uncommented lines left in this file. Reboot, and use the NetworkManager connection profiles to set static addresses... IF you still need/want them... but I can't really see why you do. Explain it to me please. Also, wifi isn't even an option in this configuration.

Comment: @heynnema  ---->   Changing the /etc/network/interfaces back to default resolved it.  But if you look at my edit, the second I try to hardcode an IP (which I must do for port forwarding etc) - my internet connection goes down again.

Comment: Enter some DNS addresses. Set auto to off. Report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and remove all of the ens33 stuff that you added, and uncomment lines 2 and 3, which should be the only two uncommented lines left in this file.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Reboot, and use the NetworkManager connection profiles to set static addresses. Enter some DNS addresses. Set auto to off.